# I have a web service date time 2016-01-01T00:00:00 which I want to format to standard datetime using C#

Tags: c#

```
Output0Buffer.Date = DateTime.ParseExact(metric.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: what is wrong with `DateTime.Parse("2016-01-01T00:00:00");` What did go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` when you  use specific format,but before need to just use `DateTime.Parse("dtString")`,try like this

> The CultureInfo.InvariantCulture property is used if you are formatting or parsing a string that should be parseable by a piece of software independent of the user's local settings.

```
 var x = DateTime.Parse("2016-01-01T00:00:00");
 var t = x.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[image]

Using `DateTime.ParseExact()` need to set format of the string representation which match the specified format exactly datetime. So your datetime format is `sortable`,using format `"s"`  you can parse  it like:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2016-01-01T00:00:00", "s", null).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.datetime.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) find how exacly use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try metric.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.ParseExact gives you a DateTime, if you are trying to see it in Debug Mode on a Watch window, the format doesn't appear, for that try to use a DebuggerDisplay attribute.
In your case just try to save it to a variable of type string and just call ToString() with the correct format as the other users are suggesting